# How to make changes to other models using post save hooks mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hook

I am trying to make changes to another collection through `post save` hook in mongoose. But I am  not sure how does it work.
I am using the following code for that.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Agents = require('./Agent')

const MonitorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    agent_id : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Agents',
        required : true
    }
})

MonitorSchema.post('save', ( doc, next) => {
    Agents.findById({_id: doc.agent_id})
    .then(doc => doc.monitor_id.push(doc._id))
    .save()
    .then(doc => console.log(doc))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    next(); 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Monitors", MonitorSchema)
```

What I am expecting of this code :
Make changes to the Agent doc and add a new `monitor_id` in the list of monitor_id.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to this question. It takes the model from the doc and then save the changes.

```
MonitorSchema.post('save',{document: true, query: false}, (doc, next) => {
    const monitor_id = doc._id;
    doc.model('Agents').findById(doc.agent_id)
    .then(doc => {doc.monitor_id.push(monitor_id); 
        doc.save().catch(err => console.log(err))})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    next()
})
})
```

I hope it helps someone at some point.